# C++ character visualization in win32 project

Tags: c++, visual-c++, encoding, character

during visualization in win32 project i have this problem, if I do something like that:

```
char temp[80]="hello";
```

and then:

```
MessageBox(hDlg,(LPCWSTR)temp,_T("titolo"),MB_OK);
```

The result is in japanese characters, what's the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: -1 The reason why you are wasting people's time here is that you have a C style cast in there telling the compiler to shut up because you know what you're doing. I.e. you're lying to the compiler, so that it won't tell you about the problem. Then you ask people here to use their time to tell you what the compiler would have told you.

Comment: +1 to Alf. Never lie to a computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luchian gives you the basic answer.

Back in the old days when I started developing Windows applications, I don't even recall there being a Unicode version of windows.  There was just multi-byte character strings.  When you created a new application using the Visual C++ wizards, it created an app where the basic string character was a "char". Sometime in there, Microsoft foresaw that Unicode was the way to go and they created types called `TCHAR`, `LPTSTR`, and `LPCTSTR`. These types compiled differently depending on whether you defined "UNICODE" in your project. If you didn't define UNICODE, then `TCHAR`=`char`, `LPTSTR`=`LPSTR`, and `LPCTSTR`=`LPCSTR`.  However, if you defined UNICODE, then `TCHAR`=`WCHAR` (or `wchar_t`), `LPTSTR`=LPWSTR, and `LPCTSTR`=`LPCWSTR`.

The current app I am still developing on is not a UNICODE app, but MBCS (multi-byte character string). Sometime in the future, I hope that it eventually will be changed to UNICODE. What I have always tried to do is use the `TCHAR` types for my strings so that in the future, all I will have to do is define UNICODE and all my string functionality will work.

That being said, you can also use the `TCHAR` functions if you don't know whether you've defined UNICODE or not:

`TCHAR temp[] = _T("hello");`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that a `LPCWSTR` is a wide character array, and you have a `char` array.

Try:

```
wchar_t temp[]= L"hello";
```

Comment: The only nitpick I have, is that it should read:  

`wchar_t temp[] = L"hello";`  

The _T() macro is when you want to make it compile for both MBCS and UNICODE--or you don't know whether it's UNICODE or MBCS. If you know it's wide char, you should just prefix the string with "L" to specify that it is a wide string--at least with VC++.

Comment: @JoeWillcoxson yeah you're right. I initially wanted to write `TCHAR` instead of `wchar_t`. +1 to you sir.